# pgfplots: marks in table as ellipse with size of error bars, area of uncertainty?

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible, and if yes how, to plot a table with `pgfplots` where the marks are ellipses with the major and minor semiaxes being the size of the error? Such that a data point is displayed as its own "area of uncertainty". Fading-out towards the edges of the ellipses would be a nice plus but is purely optional.

Unfortunately I can't provide an "already-tried-it-this-way example", because I have absolutely no idea where to start here.

Comment: If you could provide us with a drawing of what you want to achieve it would be easier to understand what your are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the existing `error bar` infrastructure to place coordinates at the end points of the major and minor axes of the error ellipses, and then draw the ellipse using a simplified version of Percusse's answer to [How to fit ellipse into another object - using intersections and calc library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74335/how-to-fit-ellipse-into-another-object-using-intersections-and-calc-library).

Here's an `error ellipse` style that does this. You can change the style of the error ellipse using the key `error ellipse style`. To get a faded filling, you could set `error ellipse style={inner color=red, outer color=white}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, filecontents}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\newcounter{mark}
\pgfplotsset{
    every error ellipse/.style=draw,
    error ellipse style/.style={
        every error ellipse/.style={#1}
    },
    error ellipse/.style={
        error bars/error mark options={},
        /pgfplots/error bars/draw error bar/.code 2 args={%
            \stepcounter{mark}
            \coordinate [inner sep=0pt] (errormarknode-\themark) at ##2 {};
            \ifnum\themark=4
                \path [/pgfplots/every error ellipse] let
                    \p1=(errormarknode-1),
                    \p2=(errormarknode-2),
                    \p3=(errormarknode-3),
                    \p4=(errormarknode-4)
                in
                    ##1 ellipse [x radius=(\x2-\x1)/2, y radius=(\y4-\y3)/2]
                ;
                \setcounter{mark}{0}
            \fi
        }
    }
}


\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
x y errorx errory
1 1 0.1 0.2
3 2 1 0.3
5 2 1 1
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=both,
    axis equal % So equal x and y errors result in circles
]
\addplot [
    mark=*, only marks,
    error ellipse,
    error bars/.cd,
        x dir=both, y dir=both,
        x explicit, y explicit
] table [
    x error=errorx, y error=errory
] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, nice. Thanks. :) Is it possible to remove the dots in the ellipses?

Comment: @FooBar: Sure, they're just the normal plot marks which don't have anything to do with the error ellipses. Just set `no markers, draw=none` in the `\addplot` options instead of `only marks`, and the dots disappear.

Comment: Where would I have to set the style with the inner and outer color for the fading? I tried putting it everywhere, but it just don't gets displayed...

Comment: @FooBar: You just put `error ellipse style={inner color=red, outer color=white}` straight after `error ellipse` in the `\addplot` options.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. :) I think I tried that, but maybe I did something wrong... Great answer. :)

Comment: @FooBar: Thanks! By the way, you can also put the `error ellipse style={inner color=red, outer color=white}` in the `axis` options if you want the same style for all plots, or you can set it gobally using `\pgfplotsset{error ellipse style={inner color=red, outer color=white}}` anywhere in your document before the `axis`.

Comment: Hm, I get `ERROR: Package pgf Error: No shape named errormarknode-1 is known` when I try this.