# Encircle an arrow in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'm preparing some lecture notes and have some trouble creating an encircled arrow like the one in the picture.

What I'd like to do is to create an elliptic shape around an arrow defined in TikZ (like the one in the code example).

```
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
```

[image]

Here's the full code for the picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-0.5,-1) node{+}
    (-0.5,5) node{-}
    (-0.5,5.5) node{Redoxpotential}
    (2,-3.7) node{Fotosystem II}
    (6,-2) node{Fotosystem I};
    \path (0.7,-0.7) node(1) {ljus}
    (2,-2) node[rectangle,draw](2) {P680}
    (2,3) node(3) {\ce{e-}}
    (3,2) node(4) {\ce{QH2}}
    (4,1) node(5) {Cyt b$_6$f}
    (3,0) node(6) {\ce{H+} lumen}
    (5,0) node(7) {Plastocyanin}
    (6,-1) node[rectangle,draw](8) {P700}
    (7.2,0.2) node(9) {ljus}
    (6,4) node(10) {\ce{e-}}
    (7.5,2.5) node(11) {\ce{e-}-redoxin (Fd)};
    \draw[decorate, decoration={snake},draw=red,->] (1) -- (2);
    \draw[->] (1.5,-2.74) to[out=60,in=180] (2,-2.24) to[out=0,in=120] (2.5,-2.74);
    \draw (1.3,-2.94) node[]{\ce{2H2O}} (2.98,-2.907)node[]{\ce{O2 + 4H+}};
    \draw[->] (2) -- (3);
    \draw[->] (3) -- node[midway,right]{\ce{e-}-transportkedja} (4);
    \draw[->] (4) -- (5);
    \draw[->] (5) -- (6);
    \draw[->] (5) -- (7);
    \draw[->] (7) -- (8);
    \draw[decorate, decoration={snake},draw=red,->] (9) -- (8);
    \draw[->] (8) -- (10);
    \draw[->] (10) -- node[midway,right]{\ce{e-}-transportkedja} (11);
    \draw[->] (11) -- (8.5,1.5);
    \draw[->] (8.15,0.95) node[below]{NADP} to[out=75,in=215] (8.5,1.5) to[out=35,in=190] (9.1,1.7) node[right]{NADPH};
    \draw (7.6,0) node[right]{\ce{2Fd + NADP -> 2Fd + NADPH}};
    \draw[dotted,->] (11) -- (5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide some example code of what you've done so far? Thank's in advance!

Comment: @Thanos Here you go

Comment: See [How to fit ellipse into another object - using intersections and calc library](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74335/how-to-fit-ellipse-into-another-object-using-intersections-and-calc-library)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that... Well, here it is again. Should probably be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can realize this drawing by *in line* calculation of the elliptic shape.

That is, you need to calculate:

1. The radius of the elliptic shape
2. The angle at which it resides.
3. The center of the elliptic shape

All of these can be performed using the `calc` library of TikZ.

Here is an example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (0,0); % Save the end-coordinates of the arrow
  \coordinate (b) at (4,7);
  \draw[->] (a) -- (b);
                  % Calculate the vector from a to b:
  \draw let \p1 = ($(b)-(a)$),
                  % radius of the elliptic shape, along the arrow:
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)/2},
                  % angle of rotation:
            \n2 = {atan(\y1/\x1)}
             % START DRAWING
            in ($(a)!.5!(b)$) circle[x radius=\n1,
                                     y radius=20pt,
                                     rotate=\n2];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Notice that in `\n1 = ...` you can also add values so that you get an extent
of the elliptic shape around the arrow.

Notice also that you can pretty much do whatever you want in this environment, by reusing the coordinates.

[image]